# Combining Two Dictionaries by Like Keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Let's say I have two dictionaries like so:

```
first_dict = {'1': 3, '2': 4, '3':8, '9': 20}
second_dict = {'3': 40, '9': 28, '100': 3}
```

Now here's the idea: I want to get all the keys that are the same, and make the entries for those keys into a dictionary of each value.

For example:

```
combined_dict = {'3': {'first_dict': 8, 'second_dict': 40}, '9': {'first_dict': 20, 'second_dict':28}}
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this for larger dictionaries?

Comment: So you're saying you do have code for this but it's slow for larger dictionaries?

Comment: no, I'm only saying the dictionaries are somewhat large and I don't have a solution

Comment: Will there only be two dictionaries, or could there be more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [dictionary view objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

```
combined_dict = {key: {'first_dict': first_dict[key], 'second_dict': second_dict[key]} 
                 for key in first_dict.viewkeys() & second_dict}
```

The expression `first_dict.viewkeys() & second_dict` uses a set intersection to list *just* the keys that both dictionaries have in common. The [`dict.viewkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) gives us a view into the dictionary that acts like a set without creating a whole new set object.

This makes the above expression more efficient than creating two sets and intersecting those, especially when dealing with large dictionaries.

Answer (score 4):

```
common_keys = set(first_dict.keys()) & set(second_dict.keys())
combined_dict = { key: {'first_dict': first_dict[key],
                        'second_dict': second_dict[key] } for key in common_keys
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works with arbitrary number of dicts:

```
def combine(**kwargs):
    return { k: { d: kwargs[d][k] for d in kwargs
        } for k in set.intersection(*map(set, kwargs.values()))
    }
```

For example:

```
print combine(
    one={'1': 3, '2': 4, '3':8, '9': 20},
    two={'3': 40, '9': 28, '100': 3},
    three={'3':14, '9':42})

# {'9': {'one': 20, 'three': 42, 'two': 28}, '3': {'one': 8, 'three': 14, 'two': 40}}
```